# Not able to use moment-mini-ts lib

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

In my angular - ionic app I was previously using `angular2-moment`, which was bloating vendor wherever I used moment due to locales.

I get to know from moment's issue tracker about moment-mini-ts.

My module is as follow:

**package.json**

```
"angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
 "moment": "^2.18.1"
```

**page.module.ts**

```
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';

@NgModuel( { 
      imports: [
              MomentModule
  ]   
} )
```

**page.html**

```
<div>time | amTimeAgo</div>
```

Source maps for vendor.js is as follows

[image]

Now replacing `angular2-moment` & `moment` to `moment-mini-ts`

Then using in module as follow displays error as :

**page.module.ts**

```
import * as moment from 'moment-mini-ts';

NgModule ({ 
     imports: [ 
       moment,
     ] 
 })
```

[image]

How to use it here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions on [moment-mini-ts npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-mini-ts) there is no need to import moment as a module.

Instead you import it per .ts file as shown below.

```
import * as moment from 'moment-mini-ts'
```